# App engine image service throws exception with jpeg output image

Tags: image, google-app-engine

I am getting an ImagesServiceFailureException exception from the app engine ImagesServiceFactory when specifying JPEG as the output format. It works fine when I specify PNG as the output format. I have only tried this on the app engine development server, not yet on the production server. JPEG is supposed to work according to the app engine docs.

Any idea why this doesn't work? I really don't want to use PNG because of the much greater size images relative to JPEG.

Following is my code:

```
    byte[] sourceData = fetchBlobData(sourceKey);
    Image sourceImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(sourceData);
   // Image sourceImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(thumbSourceKey);
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

    // Create the transform and the new image
    Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(NEW_WIDTH,NEW_HEIGHT);
    Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, sourceImage, OutputEncoding.JPEG);
```

When I output as JPEG, I get the following exception:

```
com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFailureException: Failed to encode image
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let us know too if it happens on production.

Comment: I will, but I would like to get this working on the dev server first. Thanks.

Comment: yes but if you dont try it on production, its unlikely anyone will do so for you here. To determine the cause of your error, that part is needed in your question.

Comment: When I get to the point of testing in production, I will re-post with whether it works or not and what else I learn from that testing. Until that time, I again would appreciate anyone who has any clues as to why this may not be working on the development server, or how I can get more debugging information to figure out the problem. If it works in production, that still doesn't address the issue of it not working on the development server. Thanks again for your response.